# How to append div with div's inside using jquery?

Tags: jquery, parent, drag

I have a div with all kinds of div's inside.
If i append them only the first one is draggable.
Do i have to use append parent for this or something else?

Here is a jsfiddle of my problem;

http://jsfiddle.net/nNzkr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your example with each element draggable.

http://jsfiddle.net/nNzkr/1/

```
$("#duplicate").click(function() {
    var html = $(elem);
    $("#wrap").append(html);
    html.draggable({});
});
$('.draggable').draggable({});

var elem = '<div class="draggable"><div></div></div>';
```

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple `div`s with the same id. That's invalid HTML.

Also note that you're appending your new `div` elements to the one that handles the `click` event and creates new ones.

You'll have to call `.draggable(...)` on each div as they are created.